# Which databases have analytic functions like Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, analytic-functions

Doesn't have to be the same syntax, but same or similar functionality.

Please provide the name used for the construct and a simple example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLServer/T-SQL has similar functionality.

Comment: how are they named, and what is the syntax like?

Comment: take a look here:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQLServer/Analytical-Functions/CatalogAnalytical-Functions.htm

Answer (score 2):

Here some of these:

- Microsoft SQL Server
- Sybase Adaptive Server Enteprise
- SAP SQL Anywhere
- Teradata Database